# How does including unneccesary header file affect my executable

Tags: c

Does including unneccesary header files increase my executable or affect time of compiling.

For ex. for basic input output programs i definitely need   stdio.h , but if i also include other headers like time.h, stdlib.h ,math.h how it would affect the executable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does #include affect program size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539619/does-include-affect-program-size)

Answer (score 9):

It won't affect the size of executable but yeah it will effect the time for compiling.

More includes more compile time.

Comment: some terribly broken header file might add global variables to your binary though.

Comment: @Alex agreed, but I think OP is considering the standard headers

Answer (score 4):

Header files are just declarations - hence longer compilation times.

But they do not add any extra to execution times.

Answer (score 1):

yes It Affects the Compile time of the program the more includes you use more preprocessing is required hence affects the compile time

Answer (score 0):

The title is more general then the question.

Unnecessary headers could also mean "evil" headers, mainly if `#include`d before other necessary headers.

"Random" definitions and/or "evil" `#define`s included prior to what is necessary could mess up what is `#include`d afterwards and with this definitly "*affect*" your executable.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly ***Compile times are affected, however it has no effect on execution times*** so *it's always better to add the header files that are required in the program*