# Can I implement memset, memcpy, and memmove without the c standard libraries?

Tags: c, standard-library

In a project that I'm working on, I included the lz4.c and lz4.h files from [this](https://github.com/Cyan4973/lz4) library. Because I would like to minimise binary size, I am avoiding using any std library functions. The compression library requires implementations of memset, memcpy, and memmove, and to get it to work, I had to link several standard libraries (i.e. msvcrt.lib). This increased the binary size from just under 3 kilobytes to 34 kilobytes. Can I include just these functions from the standard library or do I need to write implementations of those functions and modify compression library to use them? Thanks!

Comment: The linker will only load the modules that you reference - so you are already only including those functions (plus any others that they might reference). Writing your own methods would likely addmore than 31 K

Comment: The increase in binary size is most likely due to the inclusion of the compression library, rather than the linked system functions like memset/memcpy/memmove. You'd probably be better off finding a smaller compression library to reduce binary size. See this thread: [Does include affect program size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539619/does-include-affect-program-size).

Comment: 34K seems much bigger than a usual size of those three functions. Can you take a look a the memory map, or symbol table to see what's taking space?

Answer (score 1):

All but `memmove` can be implemented in standard C.

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        ((unsigned char *) dest)[i] = ((unsigned char *) src)[i];

    return dest;
}
void *memset(void *blk, int c, size_t n)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        ((unsigned char *) blk)[i] = c;

    return blk;
}
```

However, doing this is **strongly discouraged**, because you are not good enough to beat the compilers; nobody is. The compiler always knows how to make the fastest functions for the platform it's targeting.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll have to modify the library to not use memmove. I forgot to mention that it also uses free() and calloc(). Can those be implemented?

Comment: `malloc` can be implemented as `sbrk` (see K&R chapter 8)

Comment: I'm on Windows, so no syscalls

Comment: `HeapAlloc` then, or whatever Windows stupidly calls it. Also, `memmove` can be implemented in asm.

Comment: Thanks so much. Also, what about free? Does the winapi have a version of that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't memove be implemented? Because of some inability to compare pointers?